# How to fix BroadcastReceiver.onReceive not receive BOOT_COMPLETED action?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm going to make a service which running after device boot completed.
So I added `android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission and a receiver like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".myapp.BootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Finally, I create a BootReceiver class extends from BroadcastReceiver like this:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("RECEIVER", "BOOT RECEIVED:" + intent.getAction());
    }
}
```

But it not working. When I reboot my phone, I see a exception from logcat like this:

```
E/BootReceiver: Can't remove old update packages
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://downloads/my_downloads
at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:1329)
at android.provider.Downloads.removeAllDownloadsByPackage(Downloads.java:1089)
at com.android.server.BootReceiver.removeOldUpdatePackages(BootReceiver.java:93)
at com.android.server.BootReceiver.access$100(BootReceiver.java:42)
at com.android.server.BootReceiver$1.run(BootReceiver.java:82)
```

When I uninstall my app, this exception still appears.

What's the problem? How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It resolved.

Install app to private memory then it works fine.
Of course, when install an app, I know it install on private memory in standard.

But when you want to get some system receivers, you need to code it.